# open bootstrap select2 inside modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I have button that open MODAL. The content for this modal comes from LINK (another file - form_modal.php) - it's a dynamic content / form.

inside the modal i have SELECT2 plugin that doesn't work and i'm don't understand why.

index.php

```
    $(document).on("click", ".manage-modal", function(e){
        
        act = $(this).attr("data-act");
        ID = $(this).attr("data-ID");
    
    
        var link = "form_modal.php?act="+act+"&ID=" + ID;
    
        $('.modal-body').load(link,function(){
            $('#manage-modal').modal({show:true});
        });
    
    });
    
 <link href="plugins/custom-select/custom-select.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="plugins/custom-select/custom-select.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.select2').select2({dropdownParent: $('#manage-modal')  });
    });
    </script>
 
 
<a href='#' class='manage-modal' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#manage-modal" data-act="new">OPEN MODAL BUTTON</a>

<div id="manage-modal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Modal content (form_modal.php):

```
<form>
    <select name="contries" class="form-control select2">
        <option value='FR'>FRANCE</option>
        <option value='SP'>SPAIN</option>
        <option value='USA'>USA</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize again the `select2` inside `form_modal.php` the reason is as far as i know, the dynamic page didn't load and catch the `select2` script because it's already running when the `index.php` was loaded and the `form_modal.php` is not there when the page and script was loaded.

```
<form>
    <select name="contries" class="form-control select2 select2-modal">
        <option value='FR'>FRANCE</option>
        <option value='SP'>SPAIN</option>
        <option value='USA'>USA</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.select2-modal').select2();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: see the console in your browser, so you could see the error message @roi